# how to add constraints to limit and define valid input for the string data type in your DMN

Tags: drools, dmn

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o8Wm.png)

I wrote it like this, hoping it can't be null or "", but it doesn't work properly.

If I write !=NULL then it is right. If I write !=NULL and !="", it is incorrect and very strange.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Unary Test syntax.

```
not(null) and not("")
```

Comment: Unary Test syntax. yes! Thank you.

Comment: @Wei don't forget to accept and upvote answer if helpful